# text-decoration: underline vs border-bottom

Tags: css

What is the difference to use `{text-decoration: underline}` and `{border-bottom: ...}`?

which is easy to style and cross browser compatible?

when we should use `border-bottom` over `text-decoration: underline`?

Would it be good to use `border-bottom` always in place of `text-decoration: underline`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`border-bottom` puts a line at the bottom of the element box. `text-decoration:underline` renders the text underlined. The exact difference depends on the HTML and text layout engines in use, but in general if you want text underlined, then underline it.

Comment: yes but we can give different color than text in border-bottom

Comment: Okay. But it's still not an underline.

Comment: @jitendra-vyas now we have `text-decoration-color`

Answer (score 12):

Sorry to say this, but some answers here are misleading.  Splitting a line of text does not place the border at the bottom of the entire block, because of the nature of inline blocks.  Borders under links are actually more consistent across browsers than text-decoration: underline.

See:  [Text-Decoration vs. Border-Bottom](http://www.dennisdeacon.com/web-design/text-decoration-vs-border-bottom/)

Comment: Did this answer help you on Web Applications: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24349/29140

Answer (score 6):

As Ignacio said, `border-bottom` will put the line at the bottom of the containing box, whereas `text-decoration:underline` will actually underline the text.  This becomes an important distinction for multi-line strings.

```
I am a single line and will look similar for both methods
---------------------------------------------------------
```

would probably render the same for both styles, but you'll get the following for multi-line strings.

```
I am a string that has been
split and added a border-bottom
-------------------------------

I am a string that has been
---------------------------
split and underlined
--------------------
```

Apologies for using code formatting rather than properly rending these examples, but you can see the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: as matt said below, please test your code before answering - using display:inline; will not cause the border to render as you suggest, that is a property of block level elements specifically

Answer (score 3):

`bottom-border` lets you control the distance between the text and the underline, so its more versatile. And (as mentioned above) it allows a different color for the underline (although I don't see a reason why you'll want to do that).

`text-decoration` is more 'correct' because it is the 'real' CSS property meant for underlining text.

if you set `text-decoration: underline` for all links then you will have to set `text-decoration: none` for special links which you don't need an underline. but if you use border-bottom instead, you'll save one line of CSS code (provide you set `text-decoration: none` in your reset CSS.

so all in all, i'll vote for `border-bottom` if you have a complex layout with different styles for each link but `text-decoration` for a simple website coded 'by the book'.

Answer (score 2):

While there are always going to be cases where one is more appropriate than the other, `border-bottom` offers much more precise control over `text-decoration` and is therefore probably the preferred method. Here's a quick (likely not exhaustive) list of properties that `border-bottom` can control/enable that `text-decoration` cannot:

1. Spacing between text and "underline"
2. "Underline" style (dotted, dashed, solid, gradient, image)
3. Thickness
4. CSS transitions/animations
5. Separation of color between text and "underline"

In many cases, most of these abilities will not be needed - but it is good to have them available! I've switched to using `border-bottom` primarily for the ability to put a few pixels of padding between the text and the underline; the next most common use I've found is divorcing the underline color from the text color.

With CSS variables now shipping in every major browser, a "reset" stylesheet might look something like this:

```
:root {
    --link-color: blue;
    --hover-color: purple;
    --underline-color: var(--link-color);
}

a {
    color: var(--link-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--underline-color);
}

a:hover {
    color: var(--hover-color);
    border-bottom-color: var(--hover-color);
}
```

This way, links will display as expected on a "default" basis, yet still allow for customization as needed.

Answer (score 1):

setting your text to display inline (actually, it should be that by default) will cause the border-bottom to render much as a text-decoration rule.

however, i presume that you want to use this technique on links by doing the following:

```
/* my super eye catching dual colour link */
a {
  color:black;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

which is all well and good, but you'll find that wherever you have an img tag inside a link, the image will have a red border under it.

if you can figure out a way to target the parent of a page element (the image) using existing selectors and no javascript, i'll buy you a beer but i don't think you'll have much luck.

using "text-decoration" avoids this issue altogether as an image is clearly not text, it will not render an underline when inside a link.

if you have complete control over your markup, i suppose you can bumble your way through by adding classes to every link, but if you're working with any popular CMS system, you're going to struggle with this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this border with 1px image

```
a:hover {
    background: url("img/bg-link-hover.png") repeat-x scroll 0px 92% transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("img/bg-link-hover.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: 0px 92%;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-size: auto auto;
}
```