# CSS: Possible to set line spacing without line-height?

Tags: css

I am aware of the `line-height` property and [all the fun we can have with it](https://css-tricks.com/fun-line-height/), but is it possible to adjust line spacing some other way?

In Adobe InDesign, for example, line height and line spacing are two separate properties that can be adjusted independently.

I'm working on a design right now using a very nice Garamond, but setting the line-height to a nice legible level also makes things like links and underlines look very ugly.  Plain underlines with `text-decoration` look fine, but ideally I would like to be able to make the underlines more visually stunning and interactive, like on HuffPost's website.  They are using a `box-shadow`.  Box shadow, bottom border, anything like that will snap to the bottom of the line's height.

Can we have both with CSS?

EXAMPLE:

Normal underline using `text-decoration: underline;`

[image: Normal Underline]

Border "underline" using `border-bottom: 1px solid $special-blue;`
Seems way too far below the text, in my opinion.  Even with a moderately conservative line-height of `1.4rem`

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code here please? Line height shouldn't affect link underlines.

Comment: @NathanielFlick, you are right about that, my mistake.  I am trying to use non `text-decoration` underlines with other methods like border-bottom.

Comment: Still fine, can you post some code please so we can see the error you're getting? There's no added space to a border on an a href link that I can see in my tests.

Comment: I think it depends on your current global line-height setting as well as the font in question.  See screenshots

Comment: Cool I see your example now, it will be further away using border, but that's known behaviour, and I don't think you can fix that. It's because text underline is at the baseline, and border is below the baseline which is why there's a space difference between those methods.

Comment: Some great stuff about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467475/text-decoration-underline-vs-border-bottom and here: https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting. Playing around with this I have had some hacky-feeling success with using inline-block and height, without affecting line-relative position due to line-height adjustments.  I was hoping there was a CSS property that would be like a magic bullet... doesn't look like there is.  Tomorrow I'll post an answer here with my findings unless someone beats me to it.  At this point hacky-type stuff seems the only option.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries matey!

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, where you can set the line-height to 1 for that particular element. This resets line-height for that element, but doesn't affect anything else in that line.

by doing like this,

```
p.new a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:1px solid green;
  line-height:1;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apg6xku4/)

I believe there are no two different properties for line height and spacing.